composer install Docker
Estoy generando los contenedores Docker de una apliacion laravel en un servidor ubuntu (Local ya funciona).
Los pasos que ejecuto:

docker-compose build app
docker-compose up -d
docker-compose exec app composer install (aqui lanza el error)

0/115 [>---------------------------]   0%    Failed to download symfony/finder from dist: curl error 60 while downloading https://api.github.com/repos/symfony/finder/zipball/9915db259f67d21eefee768c1abcf1cc61b1fc9e: SSL certificate problem: self signed certificate in certificate chain
Now trying to download from source
Mi docker file

Arguments defined in docker-compose.yml ARG user ARG uid
RUN apt-get --yes update && 
apt-get  --yes install openssh-server
RUN docker-php-ext-install mysqli && 
docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql
Install dependencies RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
build-essential \
libpng-dev \
libjpeg62-turbo-dev \
libfreetype6-dev \
locales \
libzip-dev \
zip \
jpegoptim optipng pngquant gifsicle \
vim \
unzip \
git \
curl \
libmagickwand-dev \
libldap2-dev

# Clear cache RUN apt-get clean && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

RUN docker-php-ext-install gd
RUN docker-php-ext-configure ldap --with-libdir=lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/
RUN docker-php-ext-install ldap
RUN pecl install imagick && 
docker-php-ext-enable imagick
RUN docker-php-ext-install zip
###############
MSSQL support
############### RUN apt-get update 
&& apt-get install -y gpg unixodbc unixodbc-dev 
&& docker-php-ext-install pdo pdo_mysql 
&& pecl install sqlsrv pdo_sqlsrv
------------ Install MS SQL client deps ------------
adding custom MS repository RUN curl https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | apt-key add - RUN
curl https://packages.microsoft.com/config/debian/9/prod.list >
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/mssql-release.list
install SQL Server drivers and tools RUN apt-get update && ACCEPT_EULA=Y apt-get install -y msodbcsql17 RUN echo 'export
PATH="$PATH:/opt/mssql-tools/bin"' >> ~/.bashrc RUN /bin/bash -c
"source ~/.bashrc"
RUN echo "extension=sqlsrv.so" >>
/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-sqlsrv.ini RUN echo
"extension=pdo_sqlsrv.so" >>
/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-pdo-sqlsrv.ini
-------------- END MSSQL --------------------------------
RUN echo "//--- COPY SSL CONFIG ---//" COPY
./docker-compose/nginx/openssl.cnf /etc/ssl/openssl.cnf COPY
./docker-compose/nginx/cert.pem /etc/ssl/cert.pem
Clear cache RUN apt-get clean && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
Get latest Composer COPY --from=composer:latest /usr/bin/composer /usr/bin/composer
Create system user to run Composer and Artisan Commands RUN useradd -G www-data,root -u $uid -d /home/$user $user RUN mkdir -p /home/$user/.composer && \
chown -R $user:$user /home/$user

RUN composer config --global disable-tls true RUN composer config
--global secure-http false
Set working directory WORKDIR /var/www
USER $user

Agregue supuestas lineas en mi docker file para evitar el ssl
intende desabilitar la validacion del certificado de seguridad
Espero alguien me pueda yaudra, saludos a todos.

Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.
